# How to check from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var a=new Array;
for (j=0;j<=10;j++) {
a[j]=Math.floor(Math.random()*99)+2
}

var check=Math.floor(Math.random()*99)+2
```

So how do I check whether `check` is a value of any of the `a[j]` (that is `a[0]` to `a[10]`)? A good and simple method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a.indexOf(check) > -1
```

Comment: It does not work! I want that if it matches that criteria, the program can execute some code using the if statement or the ternary operator.

Comment: @user2028943: What exactly does not work? `.indexOf` tests whether a value is contained in the array.

Comment: Ya thanks, it was my mistake! It works!